# Distributing CSV values into divs

Tags: jquery, csv

I'm looking for a method for distributing data pulled from a parsed CSV structure into a sequence of `<div>` tags in an HTML file via jQuery. Any advice you have to offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the data in a varible as a comma seperated string you could do something like this:

```
const csvdata = 'data1,data2,data3,data4';
const arr = csvdata.split(',');
const html = arr.reduce((acc,item) =>  {
 acc += '<div>'+item+'</div>';
 return acc;
});

$('#mydiv').html(html);
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bonm4cs/)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help, but if the answer solved your problem could you mark as such please :)

Comment: It did! Thanks. This was my first question posed on this site! In 16 minutes, you solved my problem!

Comment: It's the circle of life ;) I've gotten alot of help here from much more clever people than me. Just trying to do my part :)

Answer (score 0):

> Use this guide,it gives you a framework to use with javascript to convert from csv to html [csv to html](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I'll check it out